# Как при наследовании классов в TypeScript определить открытые статические методы с разными (у родителя и наследника) параметрами?

Tags: классы, typescript

В примере ниже оба класса `Sample` и `Inheritor` имеют закрытые статические поля `localization`:

```
class Sample {
    private static localization: Sample.Localization = { exampleMessage1: "Something wrong." };

    public static setLocalization(localization: Sample.Localization) {
        Sample.localization = localization;
    }
}

namespace Sample {
    export type Localization = {
        exampleMessage1: string;
    }
}


class Inheritor extends Sample {

    private static localization: Inheritor.Localization = { exampleMessage2: "Something else wrong" };

    public static setLocalization(localization: Inheritor.Localization) {
        Inheritor.localization = localization;
    }
}

namespace Inheritor {
    export type Localization = {
        exampleMessage2: string;
    }
}
```

TypeScript выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
Class static side 'typeof Inheritor' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Sample'.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property 'localization'.
```

С точки зрения ООП это сообщение об ошибке странное: реализуя класс `Inheritor`, мы вообще не должны знать, какие там закрытые поля у `Sample`. Объясняется это судя по всему тем, что TypeScript компилируется в JavaScript, а нативные приватные поля в JavaScript хоть относительно недавно появились, те поля, что помечаются ключевым словом `private`, компилируются в обычные открытые поля. В общем случае это не страшно, но как объяснили разработчики TypeScript (ссылку я, к сожалению, потерял), бросание подобной ошибки было сделано для того, чтобы
избежать неочевидного поведения, когда метод наподобие `setLocalization`, будучи не объявленным на наследнике, вызывает поле (`localization` в примере выше), но не родительского класса, а своё собственное.

Конкретно эта проблема решаема, и решается она использованием нативных закрытых полей:

```
class Sample {
    static #localization: Sample.Localization = { exampleMessage1: "Something wrong." };

    public static setLocalization(localization: Sample.Localization) {
        Sample.#localization = localization;
    }
}

namespace Sample {
    export type Localization = {
        exampleMessage1: string;
    }
}


class Inheritor extends Sample {

    static #localization: Inheritor.Localization = { exampleMessage2: "Something else wrong" };

    public static setLocalization(localization: Inheritor.Localization) {
        Inheritor.#localization = localization;
    }
}

namespace Inheritor {
    export type Localization = {
        exampleMessage2: string;
    }
}
```

Но тут мы получаем другую ошибку TypeScript, вернее, с тем же кодом (2417), но другим сообщением:

```
Class static side 'typeof Inheritor' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Sample'.
  Types of property 'setLocalization' are incompatible.
    Type '(localization: Inheritor.Localization) => void' is not assignable to type '(localization: Sample.Localization) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'localization' and 'localization' are incompatible.
        Property 'exampleMessage2' is missing in type 'Sample.Localization' but required in type 'Inheritor.Localization'.(2417)
```

Вот этого я уже не понимаю. Что такого страшного в том, что у наследника и родителя один и то же статический метод с одним именем, но разными параметрами? Путаницы тут никак не должно быть, потому что если нам нужен метод родителя, то мы вызовем `Sample.setLocalization()`, а если наследника, то `Inheritor.setLocalization()`.

Это баг TypeScript-а или я что-то неправильно делаю?

### Недопустимые решения

#### Назвать метод наследника по-другому

По-другому - это как? `_setLocalization`? А если у этого наследника тоже есть наследник, то будет `__setLocalization` и так дальше нижнее подчёркивание будет отрастать по мере смены поколений?

Или может `setLocalizationOfInheritor`? Это тогда получится `Inheritor.setLocalizationOfInheritor()`? Какая-то рекурсия :)

Напротив, название метода  должно быть у всех одинаковым, чтобы API каждого нового класса была предсказуема, а процедура установки локализации - унифицирована.

#### Использовать @ts-ignore

**@ts-ignore** - это последнее средство в ситуациях, когда ничего другого не остаётся, и чтобы его использовать, нужная веская причина, и в основном это:

- Баг TypeScript-а
- Несоответствие определений типов реальному JavaScript API

Мне пока ещё не известно, попадает ли мой случай под баг TypeScript-а.

Другая проблема в том, что ошибка возникает не в месте объявления метода, а в месте объявления класса. То есть если и приглушить голос TypeScript-а, то это будет иметь вид:

```
// @ts-ignore
class Inheritor extends Sample {
    // ...
}
```

Но этот управляющий комментарий приглушит не только ту ошибку, о которой идёт речь в данном вопросе, но и вообще все, которые связаны с наследованием.
Поэтому в данном случае использование `@ts-ignore` - это серьёзная трещина в фундаменте приложения.

Comment: просто не используй static поля

Comment: @Gundy, благодарю Вас за комментарий. Есть ли ещё какие-нибудь варианты решения?

Comment: Другой вариант решения это в Sample  прописать `any` (public static setLocalization(localization: Sample.Localization | any)) Вообще не стоит обманываться на счет TS, это увы не полноценный язык (как например С# от того же прородителя), а всего лишь коробка конфет, иными словами по итогу он может не больше чем может JS (после компиляции карета превращается в тыкву) основная его задача если так можно сказать статическая проверка кода по различным контрактам (интерфейсы и т.п.) поэтому все его ошибки о том что есть нарушения подобных контрактов.

Comment: @БоковГлеб чего вы пытаетесь добиться используя наследование статических членов? Я хочу понять, почему вы решили использовать наследование статических членов в своей задаче. Можете конкретнее описать суть той проблемы, которую вы пытаетесь решить? Или это вопрос в стиле "а можно ли в typescript такое сделать"?

Comment: @БоковГлеб Я, например, хорошо вижу использование здесь общего абстрактного класса с дженерик-параметром для локализации `Parent<T>`, а в классах `Sample` и `Inheritor` наследоваться от `Parent<T>` таким образом: `Sample extends Parent<Sample.Localization>` и `Inheritor extends Parent<Inheritor.Localization>`. Вся логика будет находиться в `Parent<T>`, а классы Sample и Inheritor будут пустыми, тем самым мы избегаем дублирование кода